# Наушники отключаются при подключении к онлайн играм

Tags: bluetooth

Наушники AirPods
Адаптер CSR8510 A10
Также отключаются, когда заходишь в настройки звука или blutooth.У кого была подобная проблема?Что делац?Дрова или какое ПО может?

Answer (score 0):

Переустановите все драйвера на свежие и для наушников и для адаптера. Также зайдите в *Диспетчер устройств* и зайдите в свойства Вашего адаптера и проверьте наличие ошибок, аналогично для наушников. Также проблема возможно в том, что есть опция "автоматического отключения" (*Automatic Ear Detection*), или другая технология, которая работает некорректно.